# how to bind single field of grid with multiple values using DataBinder.Eval

Tags: asp.net

i have one hidden field and i want to bind it with two values of my data base separated by an coma. some thing like 
->asp:HiddenField ID="hfRstidDate" runat="server" Value=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "tsk_ID"),DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date_Worked").ToString())%>
pleas help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#String.Concat(Eval("tsk_ID"),",",Eval("Date_Worked").ToString()) %>' />
```